# Direct sum and $FG$ homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $FG$-module and suppose that

$$V=U_{1} \oplus...\oplus U_{r}$$

Each $U_{i}$ is an $FG$-submodule of $V$.

For $v=u_{1}+...+u_{r}\in V$ and $u_{i} \in U_{i}$

Define $\pi_{i}: V \to V , v\pi_{i}=u_{i}$

Now prove that each $\pi_{i}$ is an $FG$ homomorphism:

For $g \in G$ we have

$$(vg)\pi_{i}=(u_{1}g+...+u_{r}g)\pi_{i}=u_{i}g=(v\pi_{i})g$$

My question is why we have?:

**$$(u_{1}g+...+u_{r}g)\pi_{i}=u_{i}g$$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each $U_{j}$ is a submodule by assumption, and thus for each $j$ one has $u_{j} g \in U_{j}$. Now use the definition of $\pi$.

Comment: Sorry. I see the first point. Still unclear, $\pi$ sends us to $u$ not $ug$.

Comment: Look, $\pi$ acts like this. Take $z \in V$. You can write it uniquely as $z = z_{1} + \dots + z_{r}$, with $z_{i} \in U_{i}$. Now $\pi$ tales $z$ to $z_{i}$. Take $v = v_{1} + \dots + v_{r}$, with $v_{i} \in U_{i}$. Then $z = v g = v_{1} g + \dots v_{r} g$. Since $v_{i} g \in U_{i}$, we have $z_{i} = v_{i} g$. Now $\pi$ takes $z$ to $z_{i}$, that is, $v g$ to $v_{i} g$.